# How do you calculate the rate of ascent for frozen seawater in seawater?

Tags: thermodynamics, buoyancy, freezing, oceanography

Assuming 1m3 sphere of seawater were flash frozen at a depth of 1km, how rapidly would it start ascending to the surface given the buoyancy? Assuming we could ignore bonds between the surface of whatever actually froze the seawater and it just magically popped into the ether. Given a temperature at that depth of 5C, and the gradient of increasing temperature as the chunk floats upward, would it ever reach the surface at all before being slowly melted by the higher temperatures approaching the surface? Assume a surface temperature of 24C.

If 1m3 of seawater is not adequate to reach the surface frozen, what volume would be necessary in order to counteract the loss whilst surfacing?

Comment: Sea water doesn't freeze.  Fractional crystallization of sea water means that anything that freezes is salt-free ice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't take very long to rise. The net force is (using densities of 1000 and 934 kg/m^3 for water and ice)

$$F = \frac{4}{3}\pi * 9.8 * (1000-934) \approx 2700\,\text{N}$$

which gives an acceleration towards the surface of

$$a = \frac{F}{m} = 0.7\,\text{m/s}^2$$

So the ball will reach the surface in about

$$t = \sqrt{\frac{2000}{0.7}} \approx 1\,\text{minute}$$

ignoring drag.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Increased volume will increase both drag and surface area thus slowing the rise and absorbing more heat on the way up, but will also increase heatsink area for the rising sphere meaning that it has a higher chance of reaching the surface as ice, right? How does one go about calculating the optimal volume if your aim is to reach the surface absorbing the least amount of heat from the surrounding seawater on the way up?

Comment: A sphere maximizes volume per surface area, so it's probably best.

Comment: Yes, I'm certain a sphere is the optimal geometry, I'm just not so certain if there's a sweet spot in the volume of the sphere in order to minimise heat absorption on the ascent to the surface, to use an extreme example, obviously a 1cm^3 flash frozen at 1km will not reach the surface before it melts. But will 1m^3? 10m^3? 10,000m^3? and in each instance how much heat will they absorb expressed as say a percentage of the total available in the mass in question?

Comment: Volume grows faster than surface area, the mass scales with volume, and the amount of heat that has to be absorbed to raise its temperature scales with mass. The acceleration doesn't depend on size, so I'm thinking that bigger is always better.